# Can we show 0 instead of negative values in hyperion planning dimensions?

Tags: oracle, hyperion

The requirement is to display zero or nothing when the value in a cell negative?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple- try a `CASE` construct.

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN myColumn < 0 THEN 0 -- or NULL
           ELSE myColumn
       END AS myColumnAlias
  FROM myTable
 WHERE <myConditions>
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple years late. Hope you already figured it out.

As for your question, I believe the only solution would be to create a business rule/calc script that would check all existing data and overwrite negative values with 0. Please make sure:

1. use dense dimension member on the left side of the equation to ensure the performance and not create unnecessary blocks.
2. turn `FRMLBOTTOMUP ON`; since you only execute this calculation on existing data so it is safe and faster to use this command.